# Get a subsection from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have followign XML:

```
<ValidationObject>
<Role name='PM Front End'>
  <FileSystem>
    <Directory path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main' ValidateEntireFolder='true'>
      <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main\1.txt' hashValue='-1109720489'/>
      <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main\2.txt' hashValue='824588598'/>
      <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main\3.txt' hashValue='-1033034397'/>
      <Directory path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main\Sub1'>
        <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main\Sub1\Sub1-1.txt' hashValue='-1443348279'/>
        <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Main\Sub1\Sub1-2.txt' hashValue='-666832362'/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <!--Only two file were selected for validation purposes in the following folder-->
    <Directory path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Sibling'>
      <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Sibling\1.txt' hashValue='-444971301'/>
      <File path='C:\DeleteMe\HashingTest\Sibling\2.txt' hashValue='-431992169'/>
    </Directory>
  </FileSystem>
</Role>
```

I need to extract Direcotry XML snippet(s) from XML if ValidateEntireFolder is true. From there I need a list of all the file XElements.

I tried using XmlNode.Selec­tNodes, but that requires exact XPath to the element. The problem is that in my case, I do not know all the XPaths. The directory node can be anywhere in the tree.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq2Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var dirs = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Directory[@ValidateEntireFolder='true']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XmlNode.SelectNodes` with XPath query, even though you don't know the exact path:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("descendant::Directory[@ValidateEntireFolder='true']");
```

Hope this helps.